# Anomaly detection using mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, logfiles

I'm new to Apache Hadoop and i'm really looking forward to explore more features of it. After the basic wordcount example i wanted to up the ante a little bit. So i sat down with this problem statement which i got by going through Hadoop In Action book.
"Take a web server log file . Write a MapReduce program to
aggregate the number of visits for each IP address. Write another MapReduce
program to find the top K IP addresses in terms of visits. These frequent
visitors may be legitimate ISP proxies (shared among many users) or they
may be scrapers and fraudsters (if the server log is from an ad network)."
Can anybody help me out as to how i should start ? Its kind of tough to actually write our own code since hadoop only gives wordcount as a basic example to kick start .
Any help gratefully appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Write a MapReduce program to aggregate the number of visits for each IP address.

The wordcount example is not much different from this one. In the wordcount example the map emits ("word",1) after extracting the "word" from the input, in the IP address case the map emits ("192.168.0.1",1) after extracting the ""192.168.0.1" IP address from the log files.

> Write another MapReduce program to find the top K IP addresses in terms of visits.

After the completion of the first MapReduce job, there will be a lot of output files based on the # of reducers with content like this

`<visits> <ip address>`

All these files have to merged using the [getmerge](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.204.0/file_system_shell.html#getmerge) option. The getmerge option will merge the file and also get the file locally.

Then the local file has to be sorted using the sort command based on the 1st column, which is the # of visits.

Then using the head command you can get the first n lines to get the top n IP address by visits.

There might be a better approach for the second MR Job.

Comment: Thank you so much . Although I completely understood your explanation of first mapreduce , I will love if you'd explain the second mapreduce job a bit more . .

Comment: I'll definitely try and will let you know the result . Thank you .